# Transform JSON array of similar elements into nested array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Say I have the following JSON array:

```
[
{
    "name": "x",
    "category": "y",
    "attributes": {
        "name": "a",
        "description": "b"
    }
},
{
    "name": "x",
    "category": "y",
    "attributes": {
        "name": "c",
        "description": "d"
    }
}
]
```

How can I combine the elements where each property is identical, but add the differing properties to a nested array:

```
[
{
    "name": "x",
    "category": "y",
    "attributes": [
     {
        "name": "a",
        "description": "b"
     },
     {
        "name": "c",
        "description": "d"
     }
  ]
}
]
```

To be more specific, any differing elements should be appended to the array— for example if the attribute with name "c" had description "b", I would still want the entire attribute appended to the "attributes" list.

I've been unable to find this problem on StackOverflow through extensive searching. I appreciate your help!

Comment: If there's no existing solution then you need to try and create one. Have you tried to think through the logic of the process yourself and then write some code to implement it? Write down, step by step (the smaller the steps, the better!) how you would do this if you were moving the data around by hand (e.g. if the info was on bits of paper or something), and then try to turn that into code. We can _help_ you with that if you get stuck, but usually you'll find we don't provide solutions from nothing. Take the [tour] and read [ask] for more general guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Do non matching elements become arrays of differences? Are you expecting this to be a deep comparison?

Comment: @Shanimal ideally, this could be extended to each element in the array. The elements in each array will remain the same, but their values might change. If the values change, I'd like to append to an array. If they remain the same, we can skip and leave as a string. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to use the reduce function

```
const data = [
    {
        name: 'x',
        category: 'y',
        attributes: {
            name: 'a',
            description: 'b',
        },
    },
    {
        name: 'x',
        category: 'y',
        attributes: {
            name: 'c',
            description: 'd',
        },
    },
];

const answer = data.reduce((result, current) => {
    const findIndex = result.findIndex((item) => item.name === current.name);

    // if the name does not exist in the result, append it to the result array
    if (findIndex === -1) {
        return [
            ...result,
            {
                name: current.name,
                category: current.category,
                attributes: [current.attributes],
            },
        ];
    }

    return result.map((value, index) => {
        if (index === findIndex) {
            value.attributes.push(current.attributes);
        }
        return value;
    });
}, []);

console.log(answer);
```

Comment: I modified the inputs and posted an answer to the problem as well, but I found this to be the most complete answer to the original problem. I also was able to learn a lot about reduce & map by following along. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
//It's very simple and best for huge data
 var arr = [
       {
          "name": "x",
          "category": "y",
          "attributes": {
             "name": "a",
             "description": "b"
          }
       },
       {
          "name": "x",
          "category": "y",
          "attributes": {
             "name": "c",
             "description": "d"
          }
       }
    ];
    
    var newArr = [];
    var objKeyValue = {};
    arr.forEach(rec => {
       if (objKeyValue[rec.name + rec.category])
          objKeyValue[rec.name + rec.category].attributes.push(rec.attributes);
       else objKeyValue[rec.name + rec.category] = { name: rec.name, category: rec.category, attributes: [rec.attributes] };
    });
    console.log("Output", Object.values(objKeyValue));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Reduce can do the job. Here's one way

```js
const myJson = [{
    "name": "x",
    "category": "y",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "a",
      "description": "b"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "x",
    "category": "y",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "c",
      "description": "d"
    }
  }
]

const result = Object.values(
  myJson.reduce((acc, {
    name,
    category,
    attributes
  }) => (((acc[`${name}_${category}`] ??= {
    name,
    category,
    attributes: []
  }).attributes.push(attributes)), acc), {})
);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to slightly modify my inputs to achieve a solution (I have limited knowledge of JS). The new inputs are:

```
const myJson = [{
    "name": "x",
    "category": "y",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "a",
      "description": "b"
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "name": "c",
      "description": "d"
    }
  },
  {
   "category": "z"
  }
]
```

Now I can iterate through the items (in order). If an item lacks the "masterKey," (in this case "name"), I will add that key/value to the last item with the masterKey *or* create a list of values & append.

```
function mergeObjects_(objects) {
    var result = [];
    const masterKey = 'name';

    for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        let object = objects[i];

        if (object.hasOwnProperty(masterKey)) {
            result.push(object);
        } else {
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
                if (Array.isArray(result[result.length - 1][key])) {
                    result[result.length - 1][key].push(value);
                } else {
                    var attribute_arr = [result[result.length - 1][key]];
                    attribute_arr.push(value);
                    result[result.length - 1][key] = attribute_arr;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This collapses the sample to the following and works across multiple items

```
[
    {
        "name": "x",
        "category": [
            "y",
            "z"
        ],
        "attributes": [
            {
                "name": "a",
                "description": "b"
            },
            {
                "name": "c",
                "description": "d"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Of course, this assumes one of the trailing properties exists in the object with the masterKey. For my purposes, this is OK given how the data is generated. Thank you all for your answers and help!